# Use environment variables to feature flag features in Angular 7

Tags: angular, shell, environment-variables, development-environment

I want a way to feature flag things without having to make a code change.

I've seen solutions that involve using the `environment.ts` files where you specify which features to enable/disable. This is great for enabling features based on the environment (prod, staging, dev, etc.).

To toggle a specific feature on any environment I would need to make a code change and then redeploy. Ideally, I would like to have environment variables used in my deployment system that I can toggle and then re-deploy. I currently do this with the backend Java SpringBoot to feature flag features.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score -1):

See this article: https://medium.com/@balramchavan/configure-and-build-angular-application-for-different-environments-7e94a3c0af23

Basically, you have 2 files of enviroment with the same attributes.
When app is deploy in dev mode, enviroment.dev replace the Properties in the code by values in the enviroment file.
When app is build for production (build --prod), the builder replace the properties by the values in file .prod:

```
"fileReplacements": [
  {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
     "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
  }
```

Comment: I mentioned how I know this can be done, but to toggle features this way you would still need to make a code change(with a PR). I'm trying to avoid having to do that, and use the OS's environment variables